# XSL: Using Calculated values in further calculations

Tags: xml, xslt

The following is a shortened example of my code.

I want to calculate the average **target_value** of each **entry** in a group (or gid)
In a simple pseudocode this would be written in the following way:

```
total target_value of entries with gid "001" / amount of entries with gid "001"
```

However, since XML is fairly new to me, I wish to know how to reuse the values already calculated (see the XSL below) for further calculations?
Is variables the most effective way to go, and if so, where/how should they be defined?

XML:

```
<root>
   <entry gid ="001">
      <level_1>
         <target_value>50</target_value>
      </level_1>
   </entry>

   <entry gid ="001">
      <level_1>
         <target_value>30</target_value>
      </level_1>
   </entry>
</root>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(entry[@gid='001']/level_1/target_value)" />
```

Result:
80

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: Wouldn't the average be 40? You say 80? Do you want this average for all gid values? or just specifically '001' ?

Comment: Hi Sean,

The result 80 is from the value of select(without any average calculation)
I've got several 'gid' values in the original code, So yes, I would like to make an implementation that can be used for all 'gid' entries (002, 003..)

Comment: 1.0 would be best since it is what I've been using so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="
  sum(entry[@gid='001']/level_1/target_value) div count(entry[@gid='001'])
" />
```

Of course you can save a calculated value in a variable for re-use:

```
<xsl:variable 
  name="target_value_sum" 
  select="sum(entry[@gid='001']/level_1/target_value)" 
/>

<xsl:value-of select="$target_value_sum div count(entry[@gid='001'])" />
```

It's just not necessary in this case.

Comment: Works as intended! Thank you.

I think I'll manage to find out how to reduce decimals on my own, which is the next step now!

Comment: @Bittein Number formatting in XSLT: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-format-number

Comment: This is hard coded for @gid="001", so it is not the solution. Solution requires grouping.

Comment: @sean *"The solution requires grouping"* Wow, and you infer that from… what, exactly? Also, this is hard-coded, yes. So what? None of this makes it incorrect. The "works as intended" from the OP is also a strong indicator that this might *just* be what he was looking for, one would think.

Comment: See second comment in question.

Comment: @Sean Right. I've missed that one. The question itself primarily asks for a way to calculate the average, so that's what I did.

Comment: It's not uncommon for an OP to accept an answer that only solves the one test case he posted. Very often it's the only test case he has written. I sometimes suspect it is the only one he will ever write.

Comment: @MichaelKay That's right. On the other I think an answer on SO should not always anticipate all possible future problems but solve the problem at hand, leaving room for a different question when the OP has a new problem. In this case, my answer solves the question by title and arguably by body text. So I think voting it down because it does not address something that was not really asked for is at least disputable.

Comment: @above: No need for a fight, I got what I asked for, and It worked for what I was doing, had I needed something more (like a dynamic solution for several gid's) I would have asked for it.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

This xslt 1.0 style-sheet ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="entry-by-gid" match="entry" use="@gid" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
   <entries>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="entry
       [generate-id(.) = generate-id( key('entry-by-gid',@gid)[1])]"/>
   </entries>
   </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <entry-average gid="{@gid}">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(../entry[@gid=current()/@gid]/level_1/target_value) div
                          count(../entry[@gid=current()/@gid]/level_1/target_value)"/>
    </entry-average>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce output like ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entries>
  <entry-average gid="001">40</entry-average>
</entries>
```

For xslt 2.0, use for-each-group. Here is an XSLT 2.0 style-sheet to do the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
   <entries>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*/entry" group-by="@gid">
      <entry-average gid="{@gid}">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(../entry[@gid=current-grouping-key()]/level_1/target_value) div
                            count(../entry[@gid=current-grouping-key()]/level_1/target_value)"/>
      </entry-average>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
   </entries>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as two file-scoped variables, the first selecting the nodeset into a variable and the second calculating the mean.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:variable name="target_values" select="/root/entry[@gid='001']/level_1/target_value" />
  <xsl:variable name="mean_target_values" select="sum($target_values) div count($target_values)" />

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($mean_target_values, '0.00')" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Since you mentioned formatting floating-point numbers I've amended it to use the `format-number` function. The format symbols are the same as for the Java DecimalForamt class and the documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). I've used `0.00` which gives two decimal places. I think it's clear how to change it if you need to.

Comment: I give you +1 for format-number(). Your use of format-number() is a nice touch. But -1 because the solution is wrong. Refer to second comment on the question. To clarify, the questioner is asking for a solution for all gids. '001' was just an illustrative value.

Comment: @Sean: yes I saw that comment after I'd submitted my solution. Unfortunately grouping by an attribute isn't going to be a task for an XSL novice. I'll post another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Having seen your comment that you want to provide this information for all groups of entries with the same `@gid` I have to write a solution that is so different from my previous one that it deserves a new answer.

Unfortunately grouping in this way isn't the simplest piece of XSL, but here it is. Note that it could be made more efficient using what is known as the Muenchian method, but I have written it this way for (relative) simplicity and readability. (I see that [Sean B. Durkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10823/sean-b-durkin) has used the faster method so you can compare them.)

The way it works is that the `xsl:for-each` loops over all `<entry>` elements that have a `gid` attribute that is different from all preceding `<entry>` elements. That selects all unique values for the `gid` attribute, which are copied to the `$gid` variable.

After that, all the `<target_value>` elements inside `<entry>` elements with the same `gid` attribute are collected into a nodeset and assigned to variable `$target_values`. After that it is simple to count them and find their total, divide one by the other to get the mean, and assign that to another variable.

Then just output the `gid` attribute value and the mean for each different `gid`. The `$nl` variable is a convenience variable that is equal to a newline for laying out the output.

I hope it's easy to extrapolate from here to the final solution that you need. Please ask again if you get stuck.

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:variable name="nl">
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="entry[not(@gid = preceding-sibling::entry/@gid)]">
      <xsl:sort select="@gid" />

      <xsl:variable name="gid" select="@gid" />

      <xsl:variable name="target_values" select="/root/entry[@gid=$gid]/level_1/target_value" />
      <xsl:variable name="mean_target_values" select="sum($target_values) div count($target_values)" />

      <xsl:value-of select="concat('GID: ', $gid, $nl)" />
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('mean target value ', format-number($mean_target_values, '0.00'), $nl)" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$nl" />

    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces this output

```
GID: 001
mean target value 40.00

GID: 002
mean target value 60.33

GID: 003
mean target value 27.00
```

when applied to this XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <entry gid ="001">
        <level_1>
            <target_value>50</target_value>
        </level_1>
    </entry>
    <entry gid ="001">
        <level_1>
            <target_value>30</target_value>
        </level_1>
    </entry>
    <entry gid ="002">
        <level_1>
            <target_value>40</target_value>
        </level_1>
    </entry>
    <entry gid ="002">
        <level_1>
            <target_value>72</target_value>
        </level_1>
    </entry>
    <entry gid ="002">
        <level_1>
            <target_value>69</target_value>
        </level_1>
    </entry>
    <entry gid ="003">
        <level_1>
            <target_value>14</target_value>
        </level_1>
    </entry>
    <entry gid ="003">
        <level_1>
            <target_value>44</target_value>
        </level_1>
    </entry>
    <entry gid ="003">
        <level_1>
            <target_value>23</target_value>
        </level_1>
    </entry>
</root>
```